# Replacing a line in a new textfile

Tags: java, replace, java.util.scanner, printwriter

I have a textfile with several lines.

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
...
```

I am trying for example to replace line 3 with a new sentence.

I tred using the code below, but instead of replacing it, it just adds the new sentence next to it and the rest of the text as well. I need it to be removed and place the new sentence in the same spot, and then continue the writing of the rest of the lines. What should I fix?

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filenew, true));
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(line 2)) {        
            line = line.replaceAll("", "new sentence");
        }  
        out.write(line);
        out.write("\n");
    }   

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    scanner.close();
} 
catch (IOException e)  {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop you are looking for is something like

```
String targetText = "... the text to search";
String replacement = "The new text";
PrintWriter out = mkPrintWriter(/*...*/);

while (in.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = in.nextLine();
  if (line.equals(targetText)) {
    out.println(replacement);
  } else {
    out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Note that the out file is a temporary resource. After processing, you can unlink the old file and rename the temp file.

Comment: This does not work properly in my case because it does not repalce the line. It simply places the new line. I need to replace the line in the if condition with a new one. I want to use the replace method so that it is more accurate

Comment: @user3211165 can you make an example?

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
line = line.replaceAll("", "new sentence");
```

to

```
line = line.replaceAll(line 2, "new sentence");
```